# How to handle dates in Solidity and web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

Let's say I want to store a birth date in in a solidity contract. Which data type do I have to use in the solidity contract? How do I write the date with web3 to the contract and how do I retrieve it from the contract in a human readable format?

Comment: Related question for handling dates using solidity https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/how-do-you-work-with-date-and-time-on-ethereum-platform. Thank you

Comment: Related:  [How do you work with Date and time on Ethereum platform](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/how-do-you-work-with-date-and-time-on-ethereum-platform)

Answer (score 21):

In Solidity you will store date as `uint` type

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract BirthDate {
    uint256 public birthdate;

    function set(uint256 _birthdate) public {
        birthdate = _birthdate;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint _birthdate) {
        return birthdate;
    }
}
```

To set date in smart-contract with web3.js:

```
let date = (new Date()).getTime();
let birthDateInUnixTimestamp = date / 1000;
await BirthDate.methods.set(birthDateInUnixTimestamp).send(opts);
```

To get date from smart-contract with web3.js:

```
let birthDateInUnixTimestamp = await BirthDate.methods.get().call();
let date = new Date(birthDateInUnixTimestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: Note that a getter `function birthdate() view returns uint256 { return birthdate;}` is automatically added by its keyword `public`.